# add billing address field in magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, attributes, magento-1.7, addition

I need to add a one new billing address field

which should be shown in frontend and admin both also in packaging slip.

For this I have search on google and I found the below link

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend

I have exactly follow all the steps they have suggested ,

but the new field is not appeared in the admin at the customer address section.

I am using the magento1.7.02 version.

Please suggest me what could be the issue or the changes should be.

Answer (score 0):

I have added fields in magento admin panel

using the steps given in the link, directly in the database.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address

Then insert a record and check.

For checkout page, add the field in the path

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

Then you have add the address format using the above url.  Kindly let me know, if you have any clarification.